# While Loop Won't Stop Repeating

Tags: python, while-loop

My code surrounding the while loop is, for the most part, working fine. However the while loop won't stop repeating even if the user inputs 5 which should make it exit. This now includes all code relevant to the function I am trying to debug, I apologize for any confusion:

```
def dinos():
welcomeTheCustomer()
selection = "\0"
while selection != "4":
    selection = requestUserInput()

    if selection is "1":
        order()
    elif selection is "2":
        checkOut()
    elif selection is "3":
        startOver()

print("Have a good day!")


def askUserToChooseADonut():
print("\n -MENU-\n 1.Strawberry Twizzler\n 2.Chocolate-dipped Maple Puff\n    3.Vanilla Chai Strudel\n 4.Honey-Drizzled Lemon Dutchie\n 5.Done\n")
donutChoice = int(raw_input("Please enter a selection: "))
return(donutChoice)

def askUserToSpecifyDonutQuantity():
donutQuantity = "d"
while not donutQuantity.isdigit():
    donutQuantity = str(raw_input("Please enter a quantity of donuts: "))
return int(donutQuantity)
print ("Confirmed")

def order():
donutChoice = 0

donutQuantity1 = 0
donutQuantity2 = 0
donutQuantity3 = 0
donutQuantity4 = 0

while not (donutChoice == 5): # loop until the customer selects '5. Done'
    donutChoice = int(askUserToChooseADonut())
    donutQuantity = askUserToSpecifyDonutQuantity()

    if donutChoice is 1:
        donutQuantity1 = donutQuantity
    elif donutChoice is 2:
        donutQuantity2 = donutQuantity
    elif donutChoice is 3:
        donutQuantity3 = donutQuantity
    elif donutChoice is 4:
        donutQuantity4 = donutQuantity

return (donutQuantity1, donutQuantity2, donutQuantity3, donutQuantity4)
```

Comment: `is` is not the same as `==`.

Comment: Also is `donutChoice` an integer or a string? `"5" != 5`.

Comment: Python uses indentation sensitive syntax .... Please use the edit link on your question and fix the code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a difference between \`==\` and \`is\` in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

you are testing donutChoice to a string in this line

```
while donutChoice != "5":
```

but with an int in this one

```
if donutChoice is 1:
```

I assume the variable donutChoice is an int so your while loop should be like this

```
while donutChoice != 5
```

(Btw, I think [you should use '==' instead of 'is'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-in-python-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce)).

Comment: It is an integer but even when changing "5" to 5 the while loop will not stop repeating. I need it to loop as long as donutChoice is not equal to 5 so I don't understand how using == would help?

Comment: I recommend you to add some log lines and print out `type(donutChoice)`, `donutChoice==5` and `donutChoice=="5"`, for an easier debug

Comment: I added donutChoice==5 to the code but I don't understand what you mean by log lines? Sorry I am very new to coding.

Comment: By "log lines" I meant that you "log" (by printing) what you are doing. After the `while` line, add a line like this: `print "donutChoice: '%s', type:'%s', comp1:'%s', comp2:'%s'" % (donutChoice, type(donutChoice), donutChoice==5, donutChoice=="5")` and tell us what you see. That line should print some useful information every time you enter the loop: the value of donutChoice and its type, and the value of its comparison (both with `5` and `"5"`

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you're missing a main concept in Python: `7` and `"7"` are **NOT** the same.

```
>>> a = 7
>>> b= "7"

>>> print(type(a))
<class 'int'>

>>> print(type(b))
<class 'str'>
```

Having `while != 5` will continue looping for `[-inf-4] U [6-inf]`. But if you change to `while <5` will loop only for `[-inf-4]`.

Comment: I incorrectly made donutChoice a string, however changing it to an integer did not solve the issue, thank you!

Comment: Change it to `while < 5`

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing strings and integers. Convert everything to int. Ideally, the functions should all return integers.

Also, it appears that you do not have to use all those similar variables. Instead, use a list:

```
donutChoice = 0
donutQuantity = [0] * N_DONUT

while donutChoice in range(5):
    donutChoice = int(askUserToChooseADonut())
    quantity = int(askUserToSpecifyDonutQuantity())
    # There should be verification in "askUserToChooseADonut",
    # so this if should not be necessary.
    if donutChoice != 0
        donutQuantity[donutChoice-1] += quantity
return donutQuantity
```

Answer (score 0):

With this code, you're accepting input as a string, and comparing it to an integer.

```
while donutChoice != 5: # loop until the customer selects '5. Done'
    donutChoice = askUserToChooseADonut()
```

Change this to force the input to be an integer:

```
while donutChoice != 5: # loop until the customer selects '5. Done'
    donutChoice = int(askUserToChooseADonut())
```

(You should do the same for your donut quantity if this is expected to be an integer)

From the console, you can see why `donutChoice` will never equal 5.

```
>>> "1" == 1
False
```

Furthermore, you should change all your `if donutChoice is ...` to `if donutChoice == ...`.  It will work for low integers, because python interns numbers between 1 and 256 for better performance (so `is` will work), it will start to behave weirdly if these numbers grow.  It's recommended to always use `==` for integer comparisons.

```
>>> a = 1
>>> a is 1
True
>>> a = 257
>>> a is 257
False
```

Answer (score 0):

**This Code is working fine for me. I'm using python 3.3.3**

def order():

```
donutChoice = "0"

donutQuantity1 = 0
donutQuantity2 = 0
donutQuantity3 = 0
donutQuantity4 = 0

while donutChoice != "5": # loop until the customer selects '5. Done'
    donutChoice = input("Enter a choice: ")
    donutQuantity = input("Enter the Quantity: ")

    if donutChoice is 1:
        donutQuantity1 = donutQuantity
    elif donutChoice is 2:
        donutQuantity2 = donutQuantity
    elif donutChoice is 3:
        donutQuantity3 = donutQuantity
    elif donutChoice is 4:
        donutQuantity4 = donutQuantity

return (donutQuantity1, donutQuantity2, donutQuantity3, donutQuantity4)
```

order()

**TUSHAR**

Comment: Thank you but I'm required by this class to use 2.7.1